# Why only gravity is used in calculating the change in the potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Suppose I lift a stone of mass $m$ by placing it on the palm, from the ground to a height $h$. There are clearly two forces on the stone. One is the weight of the stone acting downward, and the other is the normal reaction exerted by the palm on the stone. Why is only one of the forces i.e., gravity is used in calculating the change in the potential energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is to assign the gravitational potential energy to the stone alone.
The gravitational potential energy is something which the stone and the Earth possess together.

When you consider the stone as a system you do indeed have two forces acting on the stone, the Earth pulling down on the stone and the palm pushing up on the stone.
If these two forces are equal in magnitude then the net force on the stone is zero and so the net work done on the stone is zero which is shown by there being no change in the kinetic energy of the stone.

The change in gravitational potential energy on a system of masses is the work done on the system by external forces in changing the relative positions of the masses.
This implies that a single mass eg your stone, cannot possess gravitational potential energy.
The gravitational potential energy is possessed **jointly** by the stone and the Earth.

An alternative definition is to substitute the words *the work done on a system by an external force* with *minus the work done on a system by gravitational forces*.

So you can use either the force exerted by the palm of the man or the gravitational attractive force due to the Earth when evaluate the gravitational potential energy of the stone and Earth system.

Comment: Do you mean if I want to include the gravitational potential energy, I cannot  use the work-energy theorem for the stone alone? @Farcher

Comment: @mithusengupta123 If the stone alone is your system and it is in free fall then you can say that work done by the gravitational (external) force will equal the change in the kinetic energy of the stone.

Answer (score 0):

The "weight" of the stone is determined by both its mass and the earth's gravitation. On the moon, which has $\frac{1}{6}^{th}$ the gravity of earth, the stone would weigh only $\frac{1}{6}^{th}$ of what it does on earth. The mass, on the other hand, will not have changed.

The "reaction" by the palm of the earth is caused by [Newton's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion): when the stone is not moving, the force of gravity must be counteracted by another force, in this case your muscle force, which stops the stone from falling.

When you take your hand away, at the moment you do so the stone will still have the same potential energy. However, as it starts to fall, that potential energy will start being converted into kinetic energy. As it drops, it will gain kinetic energy and lose potential energy.

Potential energy in a gravitational field has nothing to do with your hand. Regardless of whether or not you are supporting the stone, its potential energy is with reference to the earth. You could also calculate its potential energy relative to the moon, the sun, or any other object you care to mention. All of those values will of course be different, but none of them will involve the force on your hand.